# How to create a tri diagonal matrix as 1D

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, fortran

So for my application I would need to create a tri diagonal matrix. This is easy to do with any language, you loop through all rows and columns, then set the main diagonal values, the sub diagonal values and the super diagonal values.   Usually, this is performed on a 2d array.

For my application, I need to create a 1d array of "tridiagonal".  Otherway to say this is: take the 2d tridiagonal matrix then turn it into 1d.  I can just start with 2d then write some functions that convert 2d array to 1d array.  This, I can do.  I would like to know if we ca  go directly to a 1D "tridiagonal"?  For example, say the 2D array is 10*10, then my 1D array would be 100 elements long, then I would need to figure out which index is the main, super and sub diagonal.

Is it possible to do this? Please let me know and thank you

Comment: Do you want to store all elements (including all the zeros) or just the tridiagonal elements (which would be 28 in your 10x10 example).

Comment: I would want to store all elements

Comment: So, just a simple serialization? Like `idx1d = col + row * columnCount`?

Comment: Pretty much.  I would first zero out the 1d array, then loop over it and choose which index to have main, super and sub diagonal values.  The problem is I do not know how to get these indices.

Comment: That's what I wrote in the previous comment. The main diagonal has `col = row`, so `idx1d = i * (1 + columnCount)`, where `i` is the row / column. The subdiagonal is one before, the superdiagonal is one after.

Comment: So say we start with 1st row in the 2d array.  The first element at (1,1) is the first main diagonal element.  This corresponds to the 1st entry in 1darray: arr(1).  So using what you wrote: i = row/col =1.  Then we have: index = (1+ columnCount).   This would not give us 1.  By columnCount, do you mean the number of column in the 2d array, if we create it? Because then we would have (1+10) which is not 1 , using my 10x10 example.  Please let me know and thanks

Comment: That's why we usually use 0-based indexing. So row/col = 0 would give 1d index 0 (the first entry). row/col = 1 would give 1d index `1 * (10 + 1) = 11`. And so on.

Comment: The easiest way to solve this is to just do it. Make the 2D array. Fill it in. Print it out on a single line. Then look at the pattern. It should be pretty obvious.

Comment: The (i1, i2) element of an N x N array (in Fortran, e.g. A(i1, i2)) has the linear index ind(i1, i2) = i1 + (i2 - 1)*N. So A(k,k) corresponds to ind(k,k) = k + (k-1)*N = k(N+1)-N, etc. A(1,1) corresponds to ind(1,1) = 1, A(N,N) to ind(N,N) = N^2. (And, why so many downvotes??)

Comment: Why is this question tagged as `c++`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements on the main diagonal are at indexes (i, i) and there are n of them; the supra- and infra- diagonals at (i, i-1) and (i, i+1) and there are n-1 of them (i starts at 2 and ends at n-1 respectively).

An option is to use three vectors and store the elements at the respective indexes i in those three vectors.

You can also pack all values in a single vector of length 3n (or 3n-2 if you want to spare space). Add n or 2n to the index, depending on the diagonal you want to address. For an element (i, j), the index of the diagonal is given by j-i+2.

Comment: I cant get why the downvote... But your answer would be more useful if you provided some code. This is a good storage strategy for this kind of data, to be honest.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues: this is a very standard way to deal with banded matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You can just look at your 1D array using a 2D array pointer. Fortran:

```
  integer, target :: A(100)

  integer, pointer :: B(:,:)

  B(1:10,1:10) => A

  B = 0
  do i = 1, 10
    B(i,i) = 1
  end do

  print '(*(1x,g0))', A
end


> gfortran diag1d.f90 
> ./a.out 
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

In C++ the casting is easy as well.

Comment: This is the obvious (and preferrable) way of doing it, arguably better than `reshape` because no copying is being done. Althoug, this answer does not addres some part of the question (if I got it right): *I would need to figure out which index is the main, super and sub diagonal.*

Answer (score 0):

Please consider also:

- @YvesDaoust's answer, because proposes a better storage strategy: instead of storing all the elements of the tridiagonal matrix, store just the non-zero. You could write a derived-type to encapsulate behavior, if it worths.
- @VladmirF's answer, because a pointer association maybe a better approach (depending on your use case), than copying over all the array through `reshape`, if all you want is a temporarily indexing change for convenience while working on data.

Said that, let's go to my answer.

- Populating a tridiagonal matrix is not a different problem than constructing any matrix. I don't think it really matters here. Just bear in mind that Fortran stores arrays in Column Major order, 1 based index.
- Changing the shape of your data is easy and obvious, if storage is contiuous. You can make a `pointer` association or transferring it to a new variable with `reshape`.
- Extracting the main, super and sub diagonal is also a trivial problem, and can be done with simple manipulation of the array index triplet. Look:

  ```
  program tridiagonal
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n = 4
    integer :: A(n, n), B(n**2), main(n), sub(n-1), sup(n-1)

    A(1,:) = [1, 4, 0, 0]
    A(2,:) = [3, 4, 1, 0]
    A(3,:) = [0, 2, 3, 4]
    A(4,:) = [0, 0, 1, 3]
                              ! Remember, colum major
    B = reshape(A, shape(B))  ! 1, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 4, 3

    main = B(  1:n**2:n+1)    ! 1, 4, 3, 3
    sub  = B(  2:n**2:n+1)    ! 3, 2, 1
    sup  = B(n+1:n**2:n+1)    ! 4, 1, 4
  end
  ```